# linking Custom CSS to MVC6

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I'm using MVS 2015 in web mode debugging and i have

```
  app.UseStaticFiles();
```

and i'm using Common HTTP features so what's wrong?!

Comment: Please provide full path of request in error. It's possible that you are looking resource in wrong location. Again, without full trace, it's difficult to pinpoint problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need dependencies in your project.json.

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
```

Note: ASP.net MVC by default look into `wwwroot` folder for static content. However, if you want to change it, you'll need to override it into `Startup.cs`

```
var staticContentFolder = new DirectoryInfo(env.WebRootPath).Parent;
if (staticContentFolder != null)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(staticContentFolder.FullName, "Contents")),
        RequestPath = new PathString("/Contents")
    });
}
```

Comment: I have it otherwise it would show an error and it won't compile

Comment: By default server will look into "wwwroot"folder for static files. Where are you storing your static files?